# How to display scheduling policy in kube-scheduler

Tags: kubernetes, kube-scheduler

My question is how to display the current predicates and priority policies used by **kube-scheduler**.
Note that I didn't change or overwrite them, so am wondering how can I display them, or anyone can tell me what is the default policy used in **filtering** and **scoring**.

Comment: Is this what you looking for? - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/

Comment: Yes, but this shows the available policies in kubernetes and how to configure them, my question is how the display the pilicies witch are used in my current cluster cofiguration, by command line or somthing like that

Comment: Have you seen this doc https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/scheduling/scheduler_extender.md ?

Comment: Yes i already checked this page, but they didn't mentioned how to display the current values

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem ?

Comment: Unfortunatelly not yet...

Comment: Have you heard about OPA ? https://github.com/open-policy-agent/opa-kube-scheduler

Comment: Yes unfortunatelly it didn't help me also